# Java Failed Test When Changing int to integer

Tags: java, integer, int, field

I have the method `electCouncillor` that takes a certain councillor from an array `CouncillorsSet`, puts it on a certain `balcony` queue, gets the extra councillor from that `balcony` and puts it back in the `CouncillorSet`, to determine which councillor will be taken from the array i have the private int field `CouncillorNumber`, then i realized that i cannot use int because each time i use that method i have to reset the `CouncillorNumber` value and int doesn't allow null (and if i put 0 it will always use the first councillor from the array), so i decided to change it to integer but for some reason the test fails and i can't figure out why.

```
public class Player {
    private int id;
    private int councillorNumber;

    public void electCouncillor(Region region,GameBoard gameBoard){
//Gets a certain councillor from the array CouncillorSet
        Councillor councillor = gameBoard.getCouncillorsSet().get(councillorNumber);
//Adds that councillor to the queue Balcony
        region.getBalcony().add(councillor);
//Sets the councillor on top of the Balcony in the CouncillorSet
        gameBoard.setCouncillor(region.getBalcony().element());
//Removes the councillor on top of the balcony
        region.getBalcony().remove();
//Removes the councillor from CouncillorSet that was added to the balcony
        gameBoard.getCouncillorsSet().remove(councillorNumber);


    }
    public int getCouncillorNumber() {
        return councillorNumber;
    }
    public void setCouncillorNumber(int councillorNumber) {
        this.councillorNumber = councillorNumber;
    }

}
```

This is the test

```
@Test
    public void testElectCouncillor(){
        Player player = new Player(1);
        GameBoard gameBoard = new GameBoard();
//First i create 6 councillors to be used in the test
        Councillor councillor1 = new Councillor();
        Councillor councillor2 = new Councillor();
        Councillor councillor3 = new Councillor();
        Councillor councillor4 = new Councillor();
        Councillor councillor5 = new Councillor();
        Councillor councillor6 = new Councillor();
        councillor1.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        councillor2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        councillor3.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        councillor4.setColor(Color.PURPLE);
        councillor5.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        councillor6.setColor(Color.PINK);
//Then i add the first 4 councillors to a balcony
        Region region = gameBoard.getRegionCoast();
        Queue<Councillor> balcony = region.getBalcony();
        balcony.add(councillor1);
        balcony.add(councillor2);
        balcony.add(councillor3);
        balcony.add(councillor4);
//The i add the remaining two to the CouncillorSet of the GameBoard
        gameBoard.setCouncillorSet(new ArrayList<Councillor>());
        gameBoard.getCouncillorsSet().add(councillor5);
        gameBoard.getCouncillorsSet().add(councillor6);
//This gets the first element from CouncillorSet, which in this case is the councillor5 color white
        player.setCouncillorNumber(0);
        player.electCouncillor(region,gameBoard);
//After doing the method first i verify that the element in top of the queue is 
//now the councillor Blue
        assertEquals(Color.BLUE,region.getBalcony().element().getColor());
//Then i verify that the elements 0 and 1 from the CouncillorSet are the
//Pink and Black councillors respectively (before the method the pink
//councillor was the element 1)
        assertEquals(Color.BLACK,gameBoard.getCouncillorsSet().get(1).getColor());
        assertEquals(Color.PINK,gameBoard.getCouncillorsSet().get(0).getColor());
}
```

This is the version of the method with integer instead of int

```
public class Player {
    private int id;
    private Integer councillorNumber;

    public void electCouncillor(Region region,GameBoard gameBoard){
        Councillor councillor = gameBoard.getCouncillorsSet().get(councillorNumber);
        region.getBalcony().add(councillor);
        gameBoard.setCouncillor(region.getBalcony().element());
        region.getBalcony().remove();
        gameBoard.getCouncillorsSet().remove(councillorNumber);


    }
    public Integer getCouncillorNumber() {
        return councillorNumber;
    }
    public void setCouncillorNumber(Integer councillorNumber) {
        this.councillorNumber = councillorNumber;
    }

}
```

And the error i get when running the same test is `expected <BLACK>, but was <PINK>`

Comment: Note that there are different overloads of `ArrayList.remove` for [`int` (removal by index)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(int)) and [`Integer` (which calls the `Object` overload, and removes an object if it is present, irrespective of the index)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(java.lang.Object))

Comment: Is that the only error you get? I would also expect you to get `expected <PINK>, but was <WHITE>`

Comment: @dingalapadum not if the test framework stops at the first failure

Comment: @dingalapadum yes i also get that error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from the API, there are different methods depending on the parameter type. The first remove the element in the index indicated, while the second remove the element itself no matter the index

> remove(int index)
> Removes the element at the specified position in
>
> remove(Object o) Removes the first occurrence of
> the specified element from this list, if it is present.

Edited to add an Example:

List = {1, 4, 5, 6, 9}

With int => remove(4) (remove the number with index 4)
Result: List = {1, 4, 5, 6}

With Integer => remove(4) (remove the element with value 4)
Result: List = {1, 5, 6, 9}

Comment: so `remove(Integer index)` is not the same as `remove(int index)`?

Comment: Right, it's absolutely not the same, if you want the same behaviour with Integer you should use remove(yourInteger.intValue())